# Passing values from one controller to another

Tags: laravel-5

Been at this for ages, can't find a solution. I've searched and none of the posts help, possibly me not getting it as I'm new to Laravel (5.4)

I want to be able to be able to access `$site_settings` from one controller to another. Also `$site_settings` need to be accessible on all controllers and views. I also need to get variable from URL (hence `Request` in `__construct( Request $request )` ) but it doesn't work either.

Would really appreciate any assistance.

Thanks.

See code below:

```
//BaseController
class BaseController extends Controller {

    public function __construct( Request $request ) 
    {
        $slug = $request->slug;

        $site_settings = \DB::table('sites_settings')->where('slug', $slug)->first();

        View::share( 'site_settings', ['slug' => $slug, 'color' => $color] );

    }   
}

class SettingsController extends BaseController
{
    // SettingsController
    public function index( )
    {               

        //how do I access $site_settings here and pass it on to the view?

        // return view('settings.index');
    }
}
```

---- UPDATE with Session ----

```
 //BaseController
 class BaseController extends Controller {

public function __construct() 
{

    $slug = Route::input('slug');

    if(Session::get('slug') == $slug)
    {
        dd(Session::get('slug'));
    }
    else
    {
        $site_settings = \DB::table('sites_settings')->where('slug', $slug)->first();

        Session::put('slug', $site_settings->slug);
    }


}
```

}

Comment: if you are passing variable in url, you can access it by get and pass on further.

Comment: Thanks @GauravRai, I'll try that. What about the other question of passing results from BaseController to SettingsController, could you help with that?

Comment: @devofash If your `SettingsController` extends the `BaseController` class, so it have access to all public and protected properties of the `BaseController`. Have you tried use instead of `$site_settings = \DB::table(...` the `$this->site_settings =  \DB::table(...` inside of the `BaseController::__construct(...)` method? And then recieve the site settings value via `$this->site_settings` call in the `SettingsController::index(...)` method.

Comment: If site settings don't change very often then store them in the session, otherwise you're making an additional query on every page request. Just update the session whenever the user makes a change to the settings.

Comment: @Joe, thanks. so I've done the following, but initially the dd(Session::get('slug') is always empty even though I'm setting it, why is that??